# How do I get vendor-given name of my video card?

Tags: linux, command-line, hardware

`lspci` gives me the following information:

```
$ lspci|grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF104 [GeForce GTX 460] (rev a1)
```

This is all correct, but this is generic name of the GPU. But *Driver Manager* — KDE Control Module — gives me much more interesting information: above all the options of drivers to install it says

```
NVIDIA Corporation N460GTX Cyclone 1GD5/OC
```

This is exactly the name the vendor (MSI) gave it.

How can I find out such names without using KDE utilities? I'd prefer a console-based solution.

In other words, where does the KCM take this name from?

Comment: or `sudo lshw -class display`

Comment: No, they both give the same information, nothing more than `lspci` can tell.

Comment: Try `udevadm info -q all -p /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0`

Comment: @Patrick oh yeah, `ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE` is it.

Comment: Is this question about [tag:linux]? Please tag accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `udevadm` to get this information. For example on my system `lspci` gives me:

```
# lspci|grep VGA  
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK106 [GeForce GTX 650 Ti Boost] (rev a1)
```

Querying udev instead I get:

```
# udevadm info -q property -p /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0 
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:01:00.0
DRIVER=nvidia
ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=GK106 [GeForce GTX 650 Ti Boost] (GeForce GTX 650 Ti Boost TwinFrozr II OC)
ID_PCI_CLASS_FROM_DATABASE=Display controller
ID_PCI_INTERFACE_FROM_DATABASE=VGA controller
ID_PCI_SUBCLASS_FROM_DATABASE=VGA compatible controller
ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=NVIDIA Corporation
MODALIAS=pci:v000010DEd000011C2sv00001462sd00002874bc03sc00i00
PCI_CLASS=30000
PCI_ID=10DE:11C2
PCI_SLOT_NAME=0000:01:00.0
PCI_SUBSYS_ID=1462:2874
SUBSYSTEM=pci
USEC_INITIALIZED=22791556
```

The `ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE` gives a more detailed description of the card.

As for how to know the value to use for the `-p` argument, use the first part of the `lspci` output. For example if `lspci` showed `12:34.5`, you would use `/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:12:34.5`

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a similar thing (to get the name of the OEM/vendor of the card, not just 'NVIDIA').  Turns out this is stored as *subvendor* (sometimes sub-vendor or "sub vendor").

To get **SVendor** from the cli, have to pass the `-m` parameter to `lspci`:

```
lspci -v -m
```

And to filter just video cards, run:

```
lspci -v -m | grep VGA -A 7 | grep SVendor
```

Similarly, **SDevice** (line after SVendor) might give the friendly name that you are looking for (sorry I can't confirm, seems PNY uses boring/generic names)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the real source of this information (where `lspci` and `udevadm` get this information from), look no further than `/usr/share/hwdata/pci.ids`.
This is a text file containing collected third-party information related to the `vendor`, `device`, `subsystem_vendor`, and `subsystem_device` strings from sysfs.

Though if you use a proprietary nvidia driver, you can also find first-party information at `/proc/driver/nvidia/gpus/*/information`.

So far as of this post, I've not yet been able to find any first-party information from nouveau, AMDGPU, or even radeon.

Comment: You're answering the wrong question. The reference to `pci.ids` you could find in `man lspci`. The OP asks about the marketing name of the board rather than the generic GPU name.

Comment: @Ruslan without more information (OP's `[VID:PID]`), I can't verify `ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE` from `udevadm` in the accepted answer 100% comes from `pci.ids` (though the information given in the accepted answer absolutely does come from `pci.ids`), but as far as I'm aware with the accepted answer, udev (as mentioned) very much uses `pci.ids` for that information.

Comment: @Ruslan Also after a search, the OP's given model name 100% exists in `pci.ids` under subsystem_vendor/subsystem_device (PID 0c22 and PID 0beb for me). So no, this answer does not answer the wrong question.

Comment: Oh interesting, it appears to have been there for a long time: I have both in my `pci.ids` from August 2020. I wonder whether `udevadm`'s database is more or less complete than the one from `pciutils` (or if it's the same database).

Comment: @Ruslan yeah udev pretty much relies on sysfs and some info within locations in '/usr', though I also found an interesting source in `/proc/bus/input/devices` which I believe to be kernel-generated that could also be used by udev as it contains strings I'm not finding in hwdata...  also I checked pciutils and I'm not finding any local database from it, so it's possible that could be probing the kernel for info as well, if not also using hwdata. (so far all I've found in my efforts to remove udev rely on hwdata or kernel probes)